# Fallback font for UILabel on iOS 4?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uilabel

I am using an UILabel, placed in a xib via Interface Builder. The font is set to Bodoni, which I know is only available for iOS 5 devices. When I run it in the iOS 4 Simulator the UILabel shows no content instead of showing it in the "System" default font. Strangely this problem does not occur on UITextViews.

Now the question is: is there a way to specify a fallback font for UILabels without placing the labels via code? Maybe as a global definition or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for future reference: it seems like this plugin/control is the answer to my problem:

https://github.com/0xced/FontReplacer